# When using counting process in Cox PH survival analysis in R (survival::coxph), must I use cluster term in the model formula?

Tags: r, correlation, survival, cox-model, time-varying-covariate

I am running Cox Proportional Hazard Model in R, package *survival*, function *coxph()*. As I have time-varying covariates, my data is defined as counting process, that is there is one separate data record for each *(t1,t2]* time interval. So any object *i* can have multiple records, each for different time interval.

Does this mean that I must run the model with correlation structure, i.e. do I have to use *cluster(Id)* term in the model formula ? I have not seen used *cluster(Id)* term in some examples that I found, nevertheless I am in doubt, because how otherwise would you define that multiple observations belong to one object only ? I guess if multiple observations belong to one object, we should inform the model that the errors are not independent ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The short answer is that no, you do not have to. The explanation is in the documentation of the survival package. See `vignette("timedep", package = "survival")`.

The main reasoning is that an individual is at risk only in disjoint time intervals. Since the Cox partial likelihood is a sum over event time points, at each of those time points an individual may contribute with at most one line from the data.